# VARCHAR automatically changes to VARBINARY

Tags: mysql, varchar, varbinary

I am new to MySQL. When I declare a column as VARCHAR, why does it automatically change to VARBINARY? How should I avoid this?

[image: <code>newly created database</code>]

```
Database changed                                                       
mysql> CREATE TABLE sync(
-> vlan_id INT NOT NULL,
-> vlan_name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
-> vlan_description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY(vlan_id)
-> );
```

```
Database changed
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE sync;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sync  | CREATE TABLE `sync` (
  `vlan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vlan_name` varbinary(90) NOT NULL,
  `vlan_description` varbinary(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vlan_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I fixed it running `ALTER TABLE sync CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`. Please let me know if it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have `binary` as your default character set for the server and/or for the database. You probably want to change this to prevent the same thing happening next time you create a table.

You can check by running: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server';` and `SHOW CREATE DATABASE the_database_name;`

If the database doesn't have a character set, then the server character set will be used.

You can change the database character set with a command like:

```
ALTER DATABASE the_database_name CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';
```

The server character set can be set with a command like:

```
SET character_set_server = 'utf8';
```

(Use `SET GLOBAL ...` for the setting to be made outside of the current session. Or you can set this in your config file so it survives a restart.)